# Count the number of cells that contains number in a row

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I want to count the number of cells that contain number in a row. I am trying the `COUNTA` method but it seems doesn't work. I used:

```
COUNTA(Data!$B$21:Data!$XEL$21)
```

In fact I am using the OFFSET method to create a dynamic chart. Whenever i insert a new column of data, i wish the chart could change accordingly as well.

Is there anything wrong about that?

Comment: Consider using `COUNT()`

Answer (score 1):

[`COUNTA`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTA-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509) counts the number of cells that are not empty. So, it is not the proper function you need.

Use the [`COUNT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNT-function-a59cd7fc-b623-4d93-87a4-d23bf411294c) function. It will do exactly what you are looking for.

> The COUNT function counts the number of cells that contain numbers,
>   and counts numbers within the list of arguments. Use the COUNT
>   function to get the number of entries in a number field that is in a
>   range or array of numbers.

The syntax is: `COUNT(value1, [value2], ...)`

If you use `=COUNT(Data!$B$21:Data!$XEL$21)` is will return the count of cells that contain numbers.